# python tcp server/client in 1 program

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to create a server/client TCP python program for an assignment at school. I am not good in programming at all and I am running into some problems.

With the below code I can start the server, connect to it with the same file and port but then the server crashes instantly. I have no idea what is wrong..

The complete assignment by the way is the following: Create a python TCP server/client in 1 file and connect 2 sessions to each other. Once both are connected to each other, kill 1 of the sessions and make the session that is still remaining print "error".

http://pastebin.com/07AkuHxN (code)

Please help.

Comment: You should include the crash report.  Nonetheless, a combined program is going to need multiple threads or some sort of event-driven architecture.

Comment: Well I know it can be done without threading... And by the way, the error that is was providing me with was none, because once I opened the second connection, the program just crashes without error notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 14, you are overwriting the `serversocket` when a connection is accepted.

A correct version would be

```
clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
```

with the respective changes `serversocket` -> `clientsocket` in subsequent client handling code as well.

Another possible problem that I spotted is that both client and server parts are receiving first, and sending second. This will lead to a deadlock after the connection succeeds.

Comment: I did see that just a couple of minutes ago! But nonetheless thank you!